# PowerShell: Invoke-WebRequest - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'

Tags: powershell, http-headers

I'm trying to help a developer who is trying to harden a web server against server-side request forgery.  In short, I've wrote a script that sends a "forged" HTTP request which we will use to test against the server until it is configured to not respond to such manipulated requests.  I'm getting an error on Invoke-WebRequest:  "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'" and while I've tried a ton of different combos of the below code I cannot get it to fly.  Any thoughts? (Note:  my-ef.example.com below is not the actual host)

```
#requires -Version 5
#requires -PSEdition Desktop

class TrustAllCertsPolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
    [bool] CheckValidationResult([System.Net.ServicePoint] $a,
                                 [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate] $b,
                                 [System.Net.WebRequest] $c,
                                 [int] $d) {
        return $true
    }
}
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = [TrustAllCertsPolicy]::new()

$Params = @{
Uri = 'http://192.168.1.119'
Host = 'my-ef.example.com'
Method = 'GET'
Headers = @{"Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-transform"; "Connection" = "close"; "Pragma" = "no-cache"}
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'POST' -Uri $url
```

The above code always throws the error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The
> argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
> empty, and then try the command again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$url` is never specified in your code. Did you mean to run this?

```
Invoke-WebRequest @Params
```

Comment: Nice catch.  Changing the bottom line to that does change the error to:  "Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Host'."  Any ideas on that one?

Comment: @T-Heron `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't have a "Host" parameter. You can set it as a header if needed by adding `Host = 'my-ef.example.com'` to the `Headers=@{...}` block.